# How to listen to compare event from the "Project explorer" plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a plugin that create my own Eclipse project, with a reference to the IProject inteface.

In my runtime Eclipse I have the standard "Project explorer" plugin, when I select two project I can use the `Compare with -> Each other menu`. 
I need to "reimplement" the compare procedure between those two projects, so I would like to have the event "the user pressed the compare with menu" and **handle that procedure in my code**.
Is there any event in this case? (coming from Eclipse API or project explorer...)

Any idea on how should I do? I'm open to any possibility!

Comment: The compare uses the `CompareUI` class. See the section 'Compare support' in the 'Programmer's Guide' section of the 'Platform Plug-in Developer Guide' manual in the Eclipse Help.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449, but I know how to use the CompareUI class. What I don't know is how to listen to the user press event on that particular menu, which is in the project explorer plugin.

Comment: You can't. The menu item is connected to an existing action (`org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareAction`) and there is no way to override actions.

Comment: OK, so I should implement something similar to the project explorer (already on my mind), a make my functionality there. Or is there any better solution?

Comment: You could add your own menu item to the existing view. You may also be able to use the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point to suppress the existing menu item.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on hiding the existing menu item? Is it possible in general using an existing extension point??